# нужно помочь найти ошибку в коде

Tags: python

```
a = int(input("Введите первое число: ")
g = int(input("Введите второе число: ")
d = int(input("Введите третье число: ")
if a > g > d:
    print("Число ", g,"среднее из трех чисел.")
elif a < g < d:
    print("Число ", g,"среднее из трех чисел.")
elif g < a < d:
    print("Число ", a,"среднее из трех чисел.")
elif g > a > d:
    print("Число ", a,"среднее из трех чисел.")
elif d < g < a:
    print("Число ", g,"среднее из трех чисел.")
elif d > g > a:
    print("Число ", g,"среднее из трех чисел.")
elif a < d < g:
    print("Число ", d,"среднее из трех чисел.")
elif a > d > g:
    print("Число ", d,"среднее из трех чисел.")
elif g < d < a:
    print("Число ", d,"среднее из трех чисел.")
elif g > d > a:
    print("Число ", d,"среднее из трех чисел.")
elif d > a > g:
    print("Число ", a,"среднее из трех чисел.")
elif d < a < g:
    print("Число ", a,"среднее из трех чисел.")
```

Comment: Почитайте, пожалуйста, [про отладку и какими способами она может выполняться](https://ru.hexlet.io/courses/python-basics/lessons/debug/theory_unit): "Один из наиболее достоверных способов убедиться в том, что человек разбирается в программировании — посмотреть на то, как он отлаживает программу, то есть анализирует возникающие ошибки и устраняет их. Навык отладки (дебага, debug) не появляется сам по себе, его необходимо развивать, и начинать это делать нужно как можно раньше." - то, что мы сейчас разжуем и в рот положим, мало толку, лучше не пытаться.

Comment: Так же прошу обратить внимание, что заголовок вопроса не отражает сути проблемы, а само тело вопроса вообще не освещает сути проблемы: какие ошибки вас беспокоят, в какой строчке, в какой момент выполнения (вводные данные) и так далее. Ну и конечно надо хотя бы поздороваться с участниками соощества

Comment: Да тут весь код, кроме разве что первых трёх строк, ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

начнем с того, что вы забиваете микроскопом гвозди

а если в задаче будет 4 числа или 10 чисел?

не проще ли

1. взять 3 числа
2. записать их в список
3. отсортировать список с помощью метода `.sort()`
4. взять `[1]` значение из списка

если же решать задачу в лоб через `if` (что делать не надо, учитесь программировать сразу правильно), то составляйте `if` хотя бы объединённые в логические блоки, например:

```
if a < g and a < d:
    if g < d:
        print(g)
    else:
        print(d)
elif g < a and g < d:
    # и т.д.
```

это позволит избежать кучи ошибок